# Can we use LIKE in subquery instead of IN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using following sql query

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE keyword IN ( Select Tags from Tags)
```

keyword in table are stored as `keyword1, keyword2, keyword3`

If it was single keyword the  above query works fine but i have multiple keywords and i need to search each one of them in the

I dont thing above query is giving me right result as i am comparing

`keyword1, keyword2, keyword3` with  `IN (keyword1, keyword2, keyword3)` which wont match i tried o use instead

```
 SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE keyword LIKE ( Select Tags from Tags)
```

But it generates error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

can can i make it work so it loops through each keyword in table1, Table2 is tempTable and has these `keyword1, keyword2, keyword3` in three rows

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd697/5)

Fiddle is with sample data

Comment: Do a JOIN and have LIKE as join condition.

Comment: is your number of keywords dynamic ?

Comment: This is actually confusing. the syntax `keyword IN ( Select keyword from Table2)` and `keyword LIKE ( Select keyword from Table2)` are (almost) identical, apart from `LIKE` only supports one input value; hence the error. Are you actually looking for do a `LIKE` but with wildcards? In simple terms `[Column] IN (1)` and `Column LIKE 1` are actually identical expressions. You need to explain far better here (and you have enough reputation to know how to do that).

Comment: if your server is a sql server 2016 or + you can use string_split function https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Answer (score 4):

You can do like following if you want to use pattern match.

**Using EXISTS**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1
WHERE EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.Keyword LIKE '%' + T2.keyword + '%'
)
```

**Using JOIN**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.Keyword LIKE '%' + T2.keyword + '%'
```

If it is **exact match**, you ca do like following.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.Keyword = T2.keyword
```

Comment: this might be correct answer if user is looking for something "similar" to `table1.keyword`. I think he is looking for an exact match, so the `LIKE` here is not a good idea

Comment: it could alswo work, but with big row numbers he will experience performance issues cause of the starting wildcard

Comment: @B3S OP specifically asked for like

Comment: This answer is comprehensive for the OP's vague requirement. Their use of `LIKE` without any wildcards is just odd, as it means that `LIKE` and `=` would be synonyms. The OP needs to be more specific, but this covers all the bases I can think of that they *might* mean.

Comment: @Lamu, agree and +1 to answer and your comment.

Answer (score 0):

**About your error**:
Your subquery gives you multiple results and the `LIKE` operator cant compare more then 1 to 1. 
The `IN` operator was a good idea, but
If you are looking for something in `table2` that matches **EXACTLY** a record (or more) in `table1` this is your target:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.keyword = TABLE1.keyword
```

If you are looking for anything in `table2` that is **SIMILAR** to one or more records to the `table1` use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.keyword+'%' LIKE TABLE1.keyword
```

Comment: so maybe i dont get the point, cause he looks like he needs to match the exact keyword in table2

Comment: The value with the wildcard needs to be on the right hand side of the expression. `TABLE2.keyword+'%'`will be treated as a literal string containing a `'%'` if it's on the left side of the expression; it'll only treat the `'%'` as a wildcard if it is on the right hand side. For example `'a%' LIKE 'abc'` with return false, but `'abc' LIKE 'a%'` will return true.

Comment: I have set up fiddle it is not getting me any data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd697/5

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Dynamic SQL. Check different methods for the one that has performance advantage:

SQLFiddle:

```
Declare @keywords as nvarchar(max)
Declare @Sql as nvarchar(max)

select @keywords = 
    stuff((
        select distinct ' or [Tags] like ''%' + [tags] + '%'''
        from [tags]
        for xml path('')
    ),1,3,'')

set @Sql = 'SELECT * FROM [TestTable] WHERE ' + @keywords 

exec(@Sql)
```

Not Fiddle:

```
create table a (keyword varchar(20))
create table b (keyword varchar(20))

insert into a values ('the'), ( 'quick'), ( 'brown'), ( 'fox'), ( 'jumped'), ( 'over'), ( 'the'), ( 'lazy'), ( 'dog')
insert into b values ('the'), ( 'quic'), ( 'browns'), ( 'x'), ( 'jumped'), ('quick,brown,fox')

Declare @keywords as nvarchar(max)
Declare @Sql as nvarchar(max)

select @keywords = 
    stuff((
        select distinct ' or keyword like ''%' + [keyword] + '%'''
      --select distinct ' or keyword = ''' + [keyword] + '''' --if exact match is required
        from b
        for xml path('')
    ),1,3,'')

set @Sql = 'SELECT * FROM a WHERE ' + @keywords 

exec(@Sql)
```

Comment: This is an awful idea. It's wide open to Injection if someone can `INSERT` or `UPDATE` values in `Table2`. For example, one value would be `'''; DROP TABLE Table2;--'` which would return ALL values in `TABLE1` and then (promptly) drop `Table2`.

Comment: @Larnu Good point. This is only completely safe for smaller data lengths (<20) unless data constraints are used (first protection against SQL injection). If it is safe, this method could have a performance advantage so shouldn't always be ruled out.

Comment: This is not even working it has syntax error at `as x`

Comment: It is not working it has more errors, Invalid column name 'keyword'.

Comment: @Learning Thanks. I have updated it to contain sample data.

Comment: Thanks, will this handle multiple keywords in table a in you case, what if i have multiple keywords in `keyword column` are as `quick,brown,fox`. will this work. This is my actual problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166456/discussion-between-cloudsafe-and-learning).

Answer (score 0):

if you are on sql server or +, use string_split function, else :

create function split:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_split](
@str VARCHAR(MAX),
@delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @returnTable TABLE (idx INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, item VARCHAR(8000))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @pos INT
SELECT @str = @str + @delimiter
WHILE LEN(@str) > 0 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str)
        IF @pos = 1
            INSERT @returnTable (item)
                VALUES (NULL)
        ELSE
            INSERT @returnTable (item)
                VALUES (rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@str, 1, @pos-1))))
        SELECT @str = SUBSTRING(@str, @pos+1, LEN(@str)-@pos)       
    END
RETURN
END
```

Split your values like it:

```
select * from tmp20180308 t1 CROSS APPLY fn_split(t1.keyword, ',') t2
inner join table2 t3 on t3.keyword=t2.item
```

and do your joins with other table

Comment: add you join too :), i have modified my code for example